# Spring Data Cassandra query by a property of composite primary key

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have my primary key for a table as Composite key comprised of 3 fields: id, username and email. I want to be able to query a user by either just the username or by just the email without knowing about other keys.

I tried declaring a method in repository but it gives the error `No property userKeyUsername found for type User!`

Here is my repository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends CassandraRepository<User, UserKey>{
    User findByUserKeyEmail(String email);
    User findByUserKeyUsername(String username);
}
```

I have the following class as a key for my User table.

```
public class UserKey {

@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
private UUID id;

@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "username", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
private String username;

@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "email", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
private String email;


//equals and hashcode

}
```

And this class as my User model:

```
public class User {

@PrimaryKey
private UserKey key;

@Column("first_name")
@CassandraType(type = Name.TEXT)
private String firstName;

@Column("last_name")
@CassandraType(type = Name.TEXT)
private String lastName;

@Column("password")
@CassandraType(type = Name.TEXT)
private String password;

@Column("roles")
@CassandraType(type = Name.LIST, typeArguments = Name.TEXT)
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve data, all three columns defined in the partition key have to be supplied. You can use [secondary indexes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_using/useSecondaryIndex.html) as a workaround but it's not recommended. I'd recommend identifying first all queries you would like to perform and then redesigning your data model based on them.